# Eclipse doesn't do auto-complete

Tags: eclipse

I just installed the latest Eclipse on my Mac and one problem is that it doesn't do auto-complete.

For example, I want to create "new ArrayList<>()", when I type "Arr", it doesn't automatically trigger the whole word. This is very inconvenient. The setting looks right. Please see the attached.

[image]

It triggers auto-complete when I press ctrl+space. But I want to always auto-complete without pressing the compound keys.

Answer (score 1):

Just change in the *Auto Activation triggers for Java* the `.` for this:

```
._abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, it works! But it looks slow in pulling out the suggestion, taking several seconds. How to make it faster?

Comment: Maybe this thread would be useful for speed up your Eclipse: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/how-can-you-speed-up-eclipse?rq=1