# Eclipse has been too lagging when handle copy/paste or typing

Tags: java, eclipse, lag, handle

When I copy/paste by Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V or typing code, my eclipse quite delay 3-4s to handle. Sometimes, it caused that my CPU has loaded 100%. I really need adivices for this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/how-can-you-speed-up-eclipse

Comment: Try opening not with the java editor but general text editor. Deactivate some plugins. Vary the used memory -Xmx=512m. The java editor places text/plain but also styled text on the clipboard (for pasting in Word/Libre Writer or such). So maybe you have some clipboard manager installed?

Comment: Yea, I will try

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it's maybe be a bit late for OP but i've experienced same behavior when using CTRL+C/CTRL+V (and CTRL+Space)

i've seen that ctlr may be used to perform hyperlinking. Then i mapped the hyperlinking modifier key to ALT (General-> Editors-> Text Editors -> Hyperlinking) and eclipse is not lagging anymore when i try using CTRL+C/CTRL+V

Comment: This is brilliant!!!  Exactly what was causing my issue.  Thanks a ton @MyleeKami

Answer (score 1):

It is problem only in Eclipse? It is only sometimes or allways? Can be caused by other proces running like antivirus etc? Wich one eclipse are you using? Did you tried other version of eclipse? Im using Photon, after start up its take few sec to load stuff using ctrl+space bar, but after first one is ok.

Comment: would have been better as comment, but still welcome at sharing your insights.

Comment: i'm using eclipse mars, i just use window defender as default

Comment: @Joop Eggen, yes it would be better that way, but I was unable to post comment, until now.  Nguyễn Hữu Tuấn try to update to latest version. I had problems with Oxygen, now on Photon is all ok