# Eclipse is very slow on Save Action. Any way to improve this?

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse 2019. It is very slow on Save Action. It is necessary for me to enable the Save Action to do code format and indent check. But it is really a pain to watch Eclipse busy and slow at that point.

Is there a way to improve this?

I am trying Intellij. It is much much better than Eclipse on the Save Action.

I really hope Eclipse has the same or similar performance.

**EDIT:**

I am using Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers, Version 2019-12.

I only installed two editor plugins: One for resource bundle file and one for bash file.

**EDIT 2:**

Sorry, I should say that the Save Action on ***big*** **Java file** is slow. We have many files are more than 2 thousand lines. Some of them are double, triple that size, or even more. We often see the dialog telling us that we can turn off the Save Action to shorten waiting time. I tested with Intellij. The same file, the same formatter and Save Action,  there is no noticeable delay in Intellij but Eclipse needs more time (noticeable even that dialog does not show up) to finish the action. There is nothing to do with the change itself, change many places, or change one line is the same. My guess is that Intelliji may be tracing the changes during the process and do format and Save Action only on where is changed. But Eclipse may not tracing the changes during the process and do format and Save Action on the entire file at the end.

I have no source control and other things attached.

Comment: Your Eclipse is outdated. If there is a noticeable delay on save (even slower than in IntelliJ), then the reason is often a plug-in you installed. If you can reproduce the issue with the current Eclipse version without any additional plug-in, then tell how and how long the delay is exactly.

Comment: Save Actions for what language and in what editor?

Comment: Well, I still can't reproduce it. Could you please describe how to reproduce this in the current version by giving a Java(?) example file and your Save Actions settings/perferences?

Answer (score 1):

Were you saving with Ctrl-S?

I was having a similar (or the same problem) whenever I was Ctrl-C/V to copy/paste. It seems the underlying problem may have been that my Hyperlink key was "Ctrl", so that whenever I was about to Copy/Paste, it was trying to work out Hyperlink options - stalling the editor.

[Changing the Hyperlink modifier key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62082047/39531) (*General > Editors > Text Editors > Hyperlinking*) to Alt and the slow copy/paste is no more.