# When Eclipse is building my workspace, it freezes

Tags: java, javafx, windows-8, java-9, eclipse-oxygen

When eclipse is building my workspace, it gets held up at about 19% when updating an unmodified(after project creation) javafx application. Why is it doing this and how can I fix it?

OS: Windows 8
Eclipse Version: 4.7
JDK 9.0.1
JRE 1.8

I've seen other threads about similar problems and they have suggested allocating more memory, I've allocated 1gb to each and nothing has changed, I can't allocate more without instability.

--EDIT--

On deleting the javafx application from my disk it no longer crashes

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the answer to my question was as simple as it could get, all I had to do was delete the application and then recreate it, I think when I first tried to generate it I interrupted it by ending the task because I thought it had crashed.

Answer (score 0):

This is bit late reply, but for people who still looking for this answer might help. I had similar problems and spent few hours. This is what worked for me and I no longer have any problem.

1. Delete your workspace and create a new one if its first time you started eclipse or create a new workspace and import all your projects there.
2. Also assigning more ram to eclipse also further increases speed. which can be found here:
   [How can you speed up Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/how-can-you-speed-up-eclipse)